# Thread does not free memory

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I have a memory leak in my program.

Somewhere in my code I perform a long operation in a thread. In the meantime, I display a "waiting animation". The long operation consumes a lot of memory (~800 Mo). When the operation is finished, I expect the memory to be released, but it is not, and I don't know why. I tried to `del` the thread, as well as the `deleteLater` function.

Could you give me a hand please ?

How I call the thread:

```
self.predictor = Predictor(some arguments)

def whenDone():

    # ...do some stuff...

    self.predictor.deleteLater()
    del self.predictor

self.predictor.finished.connect(whenDone)
self.predictor.start()
```

My Thread class:

```
class Predictor(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, some arguments):

        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)


    def __del__(self):

        """Method to destroy the thread properly"""

        self.wait()


    def run(self):

        # ...do some very long stuff...
```

Comment: How do you measure the memory consumption to arrive at the conclusion there is a leak? What OS do you use?

Comment: I used top and vprof (https://github.com/nvdv/vprof) to arrive to this conclusion. When I start the process involving the thread, my memory consumption increases of about 500 Mo. I use Manjaro Linux.

Comment: I have no vprof experience, looks good though. Will check out. However, if you use a simple, top-based metric your observations aren't necessary correct: the application might have freed memory, but the OS doesn't return this as such to prevent e.g. fragmentation. Pages can obviously be swapped out, and subsequent allocations will come from previous allocated memory. So a simple way to assess this: do not do the work you want to do. Do no work to see there is no memory allocated. Then, do something simple, like allocating a similar amount of data in an array. GC it, and look at the results.

Comment: An additional remark: refrain from using `__del__`. It can actually prevent GC from happening: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python

Comment: 1) should I drop ```__del__``` even if many PyQt tutorials about threads use it ? What's your advice ? 2) You seem right about the memory allocation. But can my OS use the freed memory, or is it only allocated to my program ?

Comment: 1) IMHO yes, you should. There is plenty of crappy tutorials in the world, and it's a safe bet to ignore them. Especially in QtThreads, you can attach slots to e.g. the thread finished signal3 2) yes, your OS can use this memory. If your program doesn't ask for it, it's paged out. If it does - well, then it needs it.

Comment: If you want this answered, I would suggest actually providing a runnable [MCVE]. Otherwise it is anyones guess as to which objects are leaking (it may not even be related to PyQt...)

Comment: @deets kind of answered. He should post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monitoring memory usage can be tricky. Modern OS may chose to never decrease the memory pages allocated (and counted in tools such as top) for a process. This doesn't mean the application leaks though - it can free memory, and re-allocate this without further increase in memory footprint.